# Entitfy Framework many to many relatationship

Tags: many-to-many, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I am trying to achieve a many to many relationship in entity framework. In the fast I have simply created a table with both tables Pk in them, and Entity framework detects it and creates the many to many realation ship.

Please see ERD below:

[image]

What am I doing incorrectly?

Is there many a setting which I have to enable to allow it to create the virtual members?

I am using database first

Answer (score 0):

Tutorsubject is a table (entity) because it has some other properties

Comment: Thats fine, But why is the many-to-many relationship ignored. The table can still be there. But I need a virtual entity in Tutor to subjects, and vice versa.

Comment: so it.s not look like a relationship. if you drop other fields EF looks it as relation but in this case , it is an entity . see it as a table